# Unique Bytes from a String

Tags: java

I want to get bytes from a string value( for Encryption/Decryption purposes ), 
I have used getBytes() method for that purpose, but every time i call getBytes() method, 
it returns a new bytes of array each time. 
I want a unique bytes of array for a particular string. 
How ? Also i want to store that information (string or byte) in a file, and i want to get back this information in form of bytes.

Comment: Why do you want the same `byte[]` each times and what is stopping you from writing it in a file and reading it back?

Comment: What is a *"bytes of array"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getBytes()` will not  return new byte[] every time but contents are same.
Please check the below sample

```
    byte[] b1 = "abc".getBytes();
    byte[] b2 = "abc".getBytes();
    if(b1 == b2)
    {
        System.out.println("Equal Not possible");//Not this
    }
    if(Arrays.equals(b1, b2))
    {
        System.out.println("Equal possible");//Gets printed
    }
```

As contents of Array are equal here it should not make any difference in any possible kind of encryption/description algorithm in whole Java world !

Comment: The underling classes use `StringCoding` and `SoftReferences`, if heap is low the 'cached' object will be garbage collected.

Comment: @stacker  But once this `byte[]` is passed to encryption there is no use of this `byte[]` its only needed for say one line of code. I don't think it will get garbage collected in between. Else he can use System.ArrayCopy

Answer (score 0):

If String gave you the same byte array every time, it would violate the contract of the method.  Here is why:

```
String a = "test";
byte[] abytes1 = a.getBytes();
abytes1[0] = 0; // we are modifying the byte array.
                // There is no way to prevent this!

// some other caller later on does this:
byte[] abytes2 = a.getBytes();
```

If `abytes2` was the same array as `abytes1`, it would have a 0 as its first entry and would not match the value of the string.  String.getBytes() must create a new array every time in case a caller decides to modify the array.